# Add a file to a bare repository without a clone or workspace

Tags: git

Having a bare git repository how can new files, or modifications, be committed without having to create a clone or having a working tree of it.

Comment: Came up as a wondering of another question. If it is possible to handle git through its internals as to commit something without ever touching a clone of the repo.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to update a file in remote repo, without cloning that repo first?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16077691/how-to-update-a-file-in-remote-repo-without-cloning-that-repo-first)

Answer (score 3):

You can in fact run the various git plumbing commands on a `--bare` repo.  But you need to create a tree (even if it's a plain text file)  *somewhere* in order to make a tree, and you need to create file blobs *somewhere* in order to add them to the repo in order to make that tree, and you need to write a commit pointing to that tree, and by the time you have done all that you might as well just make a working directory somewhere.

(And then for convenience, you might as well make it a non-bare clone, which on systems that have them will use hard links when possible and hence not really use up much extra space.)

But yes, if you have a very special case, you could use `git hash-object` to enter one file into the repo and get its hash, and then `git mktree` to make a tree containing the new file (and other existing files), and then `git commit-tree` to write a commit object, and then `git update-ref` to make a ref point to it.  (The process is outlined in the [Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book), as I recall.)

Answer (score 0):

- Not having to clone is having a repo locally and not sharing with anyone else.
- Not having a working tree is just having an empty repo (It may still have a head). Thus, adding a file and *not* having a working tree doesn't make sense, IMHO.

Comment: Having a bare repo is exactly having a repo that does not have a working tree. This bare repo can contain commits, branches, and tags; it can be updated through pushes or used as a remote. So it still contain data despite the lack of a working tree.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks! I'll look forward to knowing more with your question.

Answer (score 0):

Without cloning the repository you can not make any actions from your client. For any operation like adding new file or modifying you should clone the repository first.\

The only alternative would be to do it without cloning would be through your GitHub UI.