# Pushing/creating new directory on remote GIT repo without cloning whole repo, just initialized with git init

Tags: git, github, version-control

I got little bit lazy, so I wanted to take a shortcut:

I wanted to upload some new programming examples to my GIT remote repo, so I created VS solution (for non .NET pepole, just a simple directory) on my desktop. So it looks like this:

- Desktop

  - some desktop file.txt
  - some catalog
  - MyProgrammingExamples

So, in order to push MyProgrammingExamples onto GitHub repo, I navigated in PowerShell to my desktop, fired

```
git init
git add MyProgrammingExamples
git commit -m 'some message'
```

Now, I'd liek it to push it onto remote, so further I run commands:

```
git remote add 'url to my repo'
git push origin master
```

But it gives me:

> fatal: The current branch master has no upstream branch.

So I tried:

```
git remote add master --mirror=push 'url to my repo'
```

which reulsted in

> fatal: remote master already exists.

Well, it would be good that someone explain what is hapenning, but what I am really after is to how to achieve my goal, i.e. create catalog somewhere (anywhere, not a GIT catalog) and then easily push it to existing remote repository.

Comment: Git does not have an entity that it calls a "catalog" so I have no idea what you mean by "catalog" here, but you almost certainly don't want a push mirror. In general if you are dealing with some existing Git repository on some other machine, you should start by *cloning* it, not by creating a new Git repository on your own machine.

Comment: @torek I didn't mean "git entity", but something that maps to catalog on local repo. I just want to push new catalog to github remote repo. I have a workaround, stated below in my answer.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "catalog on local repo" either. Again, that's not a Git term. Your question title begins with "create new Git catalog" and ends with "clean Git catalog"; perhaps you should rephrase it? (This is probably some kind of English/other-language translation glitch.) (Polish? Anyway, as a guess, maybe by "catalog" you mean what most people call either a "directory" or a "folder"? That is, an entity that the OS requires that you create in order to hold file's names.)

Comment: @torek Thanks for remarks, I used terms catalog/directory/folder interchangeably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16077691/how-to-update-a-file-in-remote-repo-without-cloning-that-repo-first), such operation is impossible, but there's workaround:

```
# create new branch and commit to it, then push to origin
# (assumed, that remote repo is already added, as in question)
git checkout -b single_file_branch
git add file_to_add_to_repo
git commit -m 'some message'
git push origin
```

Then we switch to local repo connected to the remote one, which is up to date and do:

```
# pull newest changes (as well as the branch)
git pull
# merge branches, allowing unrelated histories (without it it would generate an error)
git merge --allow-unrelated-histories origin/single_file_branch
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new repo right from visual studio, just signin to github from visual studio and then use the git menu in visual studio to do all the stuff supported by git!