# Is there another way instead of cloning the whole repo in github

Tags: git, github, version-control, dvcs

I want to know if there is any way instead of cloning the whole massive repo into my computer? Let's say I just want to add a file or folder to a specific folder in the project and the size of project is massive (there are thousands of .png and .jpg files there and it takes an eternity to clone that file). So is there any other way to solve that?

Comment: Consider doing a _shallow clone_.... and also consider using _sparse checkout_ to only have a subset of the files in the working tree.,

Comment: Github has upload and edit buttons on its UI. Have you tried using those?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said above you can use shallow clone or github upload and edit button.

this thread might help you since there's plenty step by step answers to how to do it.

[How to update a file in remote repo, without cloning that repo first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16077691/how-to-update-a-file-in-remote-repo-without-cloning-that-repo-first)